# Проблема в добавлении картинки в ToolBar

Tags: java, android

Добавил картинку в ToolBar нормально добавилось, но с левой стороны где гамбургер иконка по высоте занимает место... на картинке более наглядно видно... Иконка должна быть без того синего бекграунда

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Разметка:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:background="@color/actionBarColor"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/topLayout">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:contentDescription="@string/headImage"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:src="@drawable/header" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**Java code:**

```
 Toolbar toolbarLay = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarLay);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbarLay);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbarLay, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: Как же должно быть в вашем представлении, опишите\нарисуйте подробно или снимите шапочку из фольги, чтобы мой экстрасенс мог все узнать из вашей головы напрямую.

Comment: без синего бекграунда который занимает место по вертикали

Comment: android:background="#20ffffff" вроде как удали эту строчку

Comment: Удалил даж линейку, не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо помещать картинку в тулбар. Поместите их в `CollapsingToolbarLayout` на одном уровне, а его в аппБар:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="456dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="96dip">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="456dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="center|bottom"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/red"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="center"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Почему-то иконка тоже исчезла...

Comment: Ну а если всё, что внутри AppBarLayout обернуть в CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Comment: попробую........

Comment: Без изменений((

Comment: Посомтрите обновлённую разметку в ответе - у меня она нормально работает - картинка на полную ширину и высоту, а сверху на ней тулбар

Comment: Спасибо Юрий. Ты меня уже который раз выручаешь... Просто мне дали задание зная что не до конца изучил...

Comment: Кстати, как поменять цвет иконки?

Comment: @Omuradil, пож-та) За цвет иконки, если не ошибаюсь, должен отвечать аттрибут в стилях `colorControlNormal`

Comment: ok! Спасибо еще раз...